# JMF Video Capture on Macbook Air

Tags: java, macos, jmf

I'm trying to work with the webcam on my Macbook Air via JMF, but `jmfinit` can't seem to find it.  I get the following output:

```
Looking for Audio capturer
Finished detecting javasound capturer
Looking for video capture devices
Capture device detection failed!
```

Any thoughts on what I can do to allow JMF to find the webcam?

Using `jmfregistry`, I click "Detect Capture Devices", but it only has the "JavaSound audio capture" device listed (which was there before the detect, because `jmfinit` added it to the registry already).

EDIT: Best guess is that, since JMF hasn't been updated in ~4 years, it simply doesn't work on OS X Lion.  My solution was to switch to using [LTI-Civil](http://lti-civil.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Try running the MediaPlayer that comes with JMF. If it can get Webcam input, then the source code will show you.

Comment: I downloaded the cross-platform Java version, and I can't find a runnable MediaPlayer.  There is a mediaplayer.jar in lib, but doesn't appear to have a main class.  Where would this MediaPlayer be?